# Jquery error message Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: jquery

We are using jquery-1.7.1.min.js for some of the operations. We have created jquery tab. 
the tab display proper in IE 8 and above version.

But when we change the document mode to IE7 Standard, it throws error as below

> Message: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
>   Line: 2
>   Char: 11482
>   Code: 0
>
> In Scrips/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Please help out to resolve this problem

Comment: 80020101 is an obscure IE error "can't compile": check your code (es. ajax calls if you have them) for extra commas at the end of array, typos or code malformed; if you can post the relevant snippet. What do you mean with jQuery tab?

Answer (score 2):

Error 80020101 means that IE wasn't able to compile you script.

Your script is probably a UNICODE file (change to ANSI or UTF-8) - you can do this in an editor such as [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) - File > Save with Encoding

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, the script file is allready having UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @user1693579 can you try ANSI? or use the Google CDN jQuery?